# Table HTML output displays as single column iin python

Tags: python, excel

```
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
me = 'xxx@gmail.com'
password = 'yyyzzz!!2'
server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
you = 'qqq@gmail.com'


text = """
Hello, Friend.
{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""
filepath="D:/Development_Avecto/Python/Associate_AppLens_Defaulters_Nov1-Dec4.xlsx"
data_list=[]
temp_csv=""
workbook = load_workbook(filepath)
sheet_data = workbook[str('%')]
Ws_range= sheet_data['A':'D']
for row in Ws_range:
for cell in row:
    print(cell.value)
    temp_csv = temp_csv + str(cell.value) + "~"
    data_list.append(temp_csv)



 text = text.format(table=tabulate(data_list, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
 html = html.format(table=tabulate(data_list, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

 message = MIMEMultipart(
   "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

 message['Subject'] = "Your data"
 message['From'] = me
 message['To'] = you
 server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
 server.ehlo()
 server.starttls()
 server.login(me, password)
 server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
 server.quit()
```

Need help regarding how to display data in multiple columns as i have four columns in excel but now all the four columns displaying as single column.

currently it is reading data from excel and mail the content but it is displaying as single column

Kindly help me to solve i have used python 3.6.

Comment: why do you conver row of data in one string in `temp_csv = temp_csv + str(cell.value) + "~"` ?

Comment: to append ? is it wrong pls advice

Comment: I didn't check how works `tabulate` but it may treat single string as single cell in table. I would rather it convert to list of lists (not to list of strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert it to list of lists like

```
data_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

using something like

```
data_list = []

for row in Ws_range:

    row_list = []

    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
        row_list.append(cell.value)

    data_list.append(row_list)
```

---

Minimal working example

```
from tabulate import tabulate

html = """
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""

data_list = [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3]]

print(html.format(table=tabulate(data_list, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html")))

print(tabulate(data_list, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="text"))
```

Result:

```
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th style="text-align: right;">  A</th><th style="text-align: right;">  B</th><th style="text-align: right;">  C</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: right;">  1</td><td style="text-align: right;">  2</td><td style="text-align: right;">  3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>

  A    B    C
---  ---  ---
  1    2    3
```

---

**EDIT:** For `pandas.DataFrame` you have to also convert to list of listd but `DataFrame` has function for this.

to numpy array which can be also used with `tabulate`

```
 data_list = df.values
```

or to list of list

```
 data_list = df.values.tolist()
```

---

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

html = """
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3]])

data_list = df.values

print(html.format(table=tabulate(data_list, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html")))

print(tabulate(data_list, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="text"))
```

Comment: I have achieved by using pandas can you pls let me know how to format the data as proper table.

Comment: you would have to convert `DataFrame` to list of lists - like with excel. But `DataFrame` has function for this `df.values` which convert to numpy.array and it behaves like list of lists. Or you can convert to list of list usin `df.values.tolist()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.There are  % values in one of the column but after reading it shows fraction like( =C2/176) any way to read same as it is in excel.

Comment: excel may have configured to display this fraction as `%` but you have to on your own convert all values `=C2/176` to number and format with `%`.